# How can I loop a set of commands in a batch file with a series of variables?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Here is part of a Windows batch file that I already have:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set files=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (filelist.csv) do (
    SET /A files=!files! + 1
    set var!files!=%%A
)
set var

findstr /i /c:"%var5%" trans.log
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 del %var5%
```

In this batch file, "filelist.csv" is just a list of files in a particular folder that is automatically generated. The quantity and names of the files in this folder change on a daily basis and when they change the list is updated. There is one file per line in "filelist.csv". The contents of each line in the file are assigned a variable named var1 through varN, and values of these variables correspond to actual file names.

The batch file then searches through another file called "trans.log". In the specific case above it searches for the file that corresponds to "var5". If it finds that file mentioned in "trans.log" then it gets deleted.

What I need to figure out is a way for this last bit of the batch:

```
findstr /i /c:"%var5%" trans.log
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 del %var5%
```

to loop for as many times as there are variables "var1" through "varN" and each time it loops, to automatically replace the variable with the next one in the series. So in the case above, if there were 10 files in the list then there would be variables "var1" through "var10". The next time the loop runs from where it is above, it would replace "var5" with "var6" and then "var7", all the way to "var10" and then it would exit the loop and move on to any other commands that come after it in the batch.

Can anyone help me with this, please? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /F "skip=4tokens=*" %%A in (filelist.csv) do (
 findstr /i /c:"%%A" trans.log > nul
 if not errorlevel 1 ECHO del %%A
)
```

This should do what you appear to want to do. Without sample data, testing is impossible.

The `skip=4` skips the first 4 lines of `filelist.csv` and feeds each succeeding line to `FINDSTR` which sets `errorlevel` to 0 if the filename is found in `trans.log`. the `if not errorlevel 1` tests for errorlevel being 0 - an the set/test cycle is executed for each line after the first 4 (skipped) lines.

Note that your original scheme would fail (if I understand your purpose correctly) if `file5` was **not** in `trans.log`.  but `file6` (or any later) **was** in `trans.log` - `file5` would be erroneously deleted and the target retained. You'd also get a series of errors for hits after `file5` because, having deleted `file5`, re-executing the delete on `file5` would find it was absent...

Naturally, the `del` command is simply `echo`ed - change `echo del` to `del` **after verification** to actually delete the targets.

Comment: I might have been a bit unclear in the original post. I just arbitrarily started with var5 or file5. I don't want to start with the 5th file every time. I want to start with var1 all the way through varN comparing which of those files are found in trans.log and delete the ones that are found.

Comment: So remove the `skip=4` - will then attempt to match each line.

Comment: This works nice and clean and without setting variables for each line in my file list. I'm going with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you're asking.

```
@ECHO OFF

@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set files=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (text.txt) do (
    SET /A files=!files! + 1
    set var!files!=%%A
    for %%i in (!files!) do (CALL :MyFunction !var%%i!)
)
REM
REM Other code can go here...
REM
GOTO END

:MyFunction
ECHO findstr /i /c:"%1" trans.log
ECHO if %errorlevel% EQU 0 del %1

:END
```

Remove the `ECHO` statements in `MyFunction` to actually run `findstr` and delete the file.

Comment: On your last line I had to change %var5% to %1 but it seems to do exactly what I want. The only hiccup which is puzzling me is after it runs I get the message `FINDSTR: Argument missing after /c`. Do you have any idea why and what can be done to correct it?

Comment: Oops...I missed the `%var5` on that line. The error message you were getting was because after it dropped out of the `FOR` loop, it ran the next line of the batch file which was the `FINDSTR` line. I added a `GOTO END` and an `END` label so that won't happen.

Comment: This does work well but I'm gonna go with Magoo's answer because its simpler and cleaner. I would upvote your answer but I don't have enough rep. Thank you for your help.